# ArcGIS Server: Execute Export Web Map Task with custom image service rendering rule

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, printing, image-service

I am trying to use the out-of-the-box *Print* ==> *Export Web Map Task* for ArcGIS Server (10.1+) a web map containing an image service layer with a custom rendering rule. The [web map json spec](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/exportwebmap_spec.html) mentions the ImageService Layer has :

ArcGIS ImageService Layer

```
  {
    "id": "<webmapOperationalLayer_imageService>",
    "url": "<url1>,
    "token": "<tokenString1>,
    "title": "<title1>",
    "opacity": <opacity1>,
    "visibility": <true | false>,
    "minScale": <minScale1>,
    "maxScale": <maxScale1>,
    "noData": <no data value>,
    "format": "<jpgpng | png | png8 | png24 | jpg | bmp | gif | tiff>",
    "interpolation": "<RSP_BilinearInterpolation | RSP_CubicConvolution | 
                            RSP_Majority | RSP_NearestNeighbor>",
    "compressionQuality": <compression quality>,
    "bandIds": [
      <bandId1>,
      <bandId2>
    ],
    "mosaicRule": "<mosaic rule 1>",
    "**renderingRule**": **-rendering rule 1-**   
},
```

When the renderingRule is included, it receive a 404 error. When I do not set renderingRule, the task works fine.  I use the same rendering rule as when I call exportImage on the image service itself.

Has anybody seen an example of Export Web Map Task **handling a custom renderingRule** for an Image Service Layer?

Thanks in advance for your help.